# Include/Exclude packages in component scan on basis of property defined in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

From Spring Boot application, I want to keep the scan of components property driven.
I am able to include the packages required from a property file but facing challenge in excluding packages.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"${app.included.packages}"}, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = {"${app.excluded.packages"}"})
```

})

Can some one help me with some reference if there is any way to exclude packages as well from the component scan via property files?

Please note that there might be multiple packages in property "app.excluded.packages" in application.properties.

Thanks & Regards

---

Amit

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `@OnConditionalProperty` (although I rather use it just for autoconfiguration)

Answer (score 0):

hi this worked for me:

@ComponentScan(basePackages ={ "{app.included.packages}},excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,pattern = {"app.excluded.packages"}))

maybe thats becuase of the $ .

Comment: Apologies, but the question is related to reading the packages details from the property file. app,included.packages is set of packages in property file & similarly app.excluded.packages is set of packages to be excluded in property file.